# Font display discrepancy safari 9.1.3

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

So I have two code elements both are styled the exact same way, both have the exact same computed styles in the safari inspector:

```
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
color: rgb(213, 93, 33);
display: inline;
font-family: monospace, monospace;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
height: auto;
line-height: 21px;
text-align: center;
white-space: pre;
width: auto;
```

The abov css is for the span that colors the word 'setf' in both pictures.

The only difference is one is nested in a section>aside>header>nav>pre>code, and the other is nested in the same section but then main>section>pre>code:

[image: full screenshot]

Here are details:

Sidebar

[image: crisp]

Footer

[image: fuzzy]

Clearly the font weight in the second one is greater, but there is no accompanying style rule I can find anywhere (i'd provide more of the css but it is a messy mix of a normalizer and some stuff). Is there something I should look for that doesn't show up in the computed styles?

Working reference for site is here: [example](https://dotmilk.github.io/bug)

The left has the thinner example and the bottom of the page has the pagination element. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well someone added an answer that sort of worked so I can not ask a follow up, nor accept it :(

Comment: Haha sorry, I looked at the question and decided I'd completely misunderstood. Glad it was helpful! Undeleted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like it might be a font smoothing problem. Does adding

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

fix it?

(note: for some reason I first thought you were seeing that difference between two browsers. If this is helpful that's great, but it now seems unlikely to me)

Comment: So do you have any idea why the code element in the main element didn't have this applied? And the one in the aside nav did?

Comment: No that's very strange. There must have been a font-smoothing style applied somewhere?? Did you already make the change on the live site? I just found the one in the footer, and they look the same to me

Comment: Haven't pushed the change to the live site yet, just locally tinkering. I want to understand why this is the case. I much appreciate the answer though, I have been trying to figure it out for two days.

Comment: And that is the other thing, on every other browser they are rendered the same

Comment: Safar: Version 9.1.3 (11601.7.8)?

Comment: Oh right, my screenshots were Chrome. I see it in Safari too. `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` fixes it. Dunno but glad it works!